# km curve sample size at t=0 with censoring and events at t =0

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

How do I calculate the $n_t$ (subjects at risk) at each time t when i am dealing with a dataset that contains both events and censored data at time t=0. Assuming I have  248 subjects in a study to begin with and within the next time interval t = 365 I lose 16, (4 events, 12 censor). This is what I did below based on my theoretical understanding of what $n_t$ is supposed to be, I could be wrong. If somebody could take a look at this and let me know if I am wrong anywhere that will help. Thanks.

```
t      Events    Censor    n  

0.00    4        12        248
365.00  3        0         232
366.00  4        13        229
730.00  3        0         212
731.00  9        0         209
1095.00 1        17        200
1096.00 6        15        182     
1461.00 9        12        161
1826.00 4        0         140
1827.00 2        15        136
2191.00 4        0         119
2192.00 1        10        115
2557.00 4        13        104
2922.00 2        30         87
4018.00 2        16         55
4383.00 1        36         37
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're basically right, but as a formality, there can not be events or censoring literally at 0. That would be like saying you start with a sample where someone has already died (for example). Anyways, it doesn't change much about your table. You just need an extra row for time 0, with no events or censoring. The n stays the same. The next row; t=1 (or whenever the first event is) is what you currently have as t=0.

[image: Here is an example from a different data set]